# SQL Show if a record exists in multiple tables

Tags: sql

Even though it looks similar to other questions here, this case is a bit different and I could not find the answer here.

I have a constant list of tables (e.g. `table_1, table_2, table_3, etc...`) that may have around 50 tables in it.
The tables may have different schemes, but ALL of them has the column `id` of integer type.

There is an input list of integers and the task is to get an output table with table names as columns and input integers as rows with a boolean value in cells: `TRUE` if a record with the corresponding id exists in the corresponding table and `FALSE` otherwise.

I'd like to retrieve the result in a single query, if possible.

Optionally, it'd be perfect also to have a column `exists_in_all` that would have `TRUE` if the record exists in all the tables and `FALSE` otherwise.

### For example:

##### Input:

`111, 222, 333, 444, 123, 456`

##### Tables:

###### `table_1`:

| id | some_column |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 'lorem ipsum' |
| 222 | 'and' |
| 333 | 'some' |
| 444 | 'random' |
| 123 | 'strings' |

###### `table_2`:

| id | some_column |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 'lorem ipsum' |
| 222 | 'and' |
| 444 | 'random' |
| 123 | 'strings' |

###### `table_3`:

| id | some_column |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 'lorem ipsum' |
| 222 | 'and' |
| 333 | 'some' |
| 444 | 'random' |

##### Desired result:

| id | exists_in_all | table_1 | table_2 | table_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 222 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 333 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 444 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 123 | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 456 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

I made several attempts with `SELECT ... WHEERE EXISTS ...`, `JOIN`s, `UNION`s, but could not get exactly what I wanted. Perhaps, I was not using them correctly.

A query for a single record could work as well.

##### For example:

###### Input

`123`

###### Result

| id | 123 |
| --- | --- |
| exists_in_all | FALSE |
| table_1 | TRUE |
| table_2 | TRUE |
| table_3 | FALSE |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is going to require a *dynamic* SQL solution. Optimal solutions will depend on your specific database platform.

Comment: This sounds like a weird task. What information would I gain from knowing that in my customers table there is an ID 123, but in my stores table there is not. Is this about database replication? Otherwise this may just be an indicator for a likewise weird database. Anyway: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Hello, please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried

Comment: Can we assume that table_2 and table_3 are subsets of table_1?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the query using conditional aggregation and `union all`.  The "all" column is a little tricky, but if you have a fixed list you can hardcode the count you need:

```
select id,
       (case when count(*) = 50 then 'True' else 'False' end) as exists_in_all
       max(case when which = 'table1' then 'True' else 'False' end) as in_table1,
       max(case when which = 'table2' then 'True' else 'False' end) as in_table2,
       . . . 
from ((select id, 'table1' as which from table1) union all
      (select id, 'table2' from table2) union all
      . . .
     ) t
where id in ( . . . )
group by id;
```

You could simplify this a bit using a view for the subquery.